# Magento2: Why isn't static content generated properly?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, static-content, static-content-deploy

I have seen so many answers related to this question but nothing resolved my issue:

[image]

I have cleared:

- `cache`
- `pub/static`
- `generated`
- `var/cache`,
- `var/view_preprocessed`

Ran

- `setup:upgrade`
- `di:compile`
- `cache:flush`
- `indexer`

Almost run all commands. CSS minfication and JS minfication and `merge` is also set to `0`, means disabled symlink in **di.xml** file is also set from symlink to copy.

I have tried reverting it to symlink also but no luck. Any other way to sort this out?

In the frontend there are so many console issues like that in the screenshot. Locale is `en_US` so **static-content command** is also correct and from the frontend **console errors** are like this image:
[image]

Comment: seems your issue has been fixed:).If you want to post the solution then please  put

Comment: issue was not fixed actually , reinstalled theme and import data

Answer (score 0):

I have problems on our site with static content. Cache and upgrade commands are not working quite right.
I find that switching the mode to developer and then back to production always remedies it though:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: yes i have tried it also but no luck ..